# How can I change the width of Material UI Autocomplete popover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using the [Select](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) from Material-UI, there's a prop there called 'autoWidth' which sets the width of the popover to match the width of the items inside the menu.

Is there a similar option for the [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component?

what i'm trying to achieve is that the width of the TextField is independent of the width of the menu, and the width of the menu is determined by the menu items rather than a hard-coded 'width.

What I managed to find so far is an option to provide width to the 'paper' component using classes (see code below), but it's independent of the actual items' width and the position of the paper isn't adjusted to stay inside the window.

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  paper: {
    width: "450px"
  }
});

function ComboBox(props) {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      classes={{
        paper: props.classes.paper
      }}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{
        width: 300,
        paddingLeft: "100px"
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7fyuw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

What i'm trying to achieve is a similar behavior to [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-icjhk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) but using the Autocomplete component. Notice that width of the pop-up menu is taken from the menu items while the width of the Select component is hard-coded.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To have a dynamic menu based on elements inside the menu itself you need to customize the Autocomplete's `PopperComponent` property in this way:

1. Define a custom `Popper`:

   ```
   const PopperMy = function (props) {
      return <Popper {...props} style={styles.popper} placement="bottom-start" />;
   };
   ```
2. In `Popper` style, set the width to "fit-content":

   ```
   const styles = (theme) => ({
      popper: {
         width: "fit-content"
      }
   });
   ```
3. Pass the component `PopperMy` to Autocomplete:

   ```
   <Autocomplete
      PopperComponent={PopperMy}
      ...  
   />
   ```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-b927n?file=/demo.js) is your codesandbox modified.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, but what i'm looking for is the opposite of what you showed. I want the Autocomplete (the TextField part) to stay the same, predefined, width and the menu (the window that opens and shows a list of all the available items), to have the width depending on the length of the items.

Comment: @VladiFeldman So for example you want that the film title "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb" appears in 1 line in menu (and not in 2 lines) correct?

Comment: Correct sir!
The width of the menu should be determined by the items inside it.

Comment: @VladiFeldman I have updated my answer (and the codesandbox). I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito How do you change the width of the dropdown manually. Let's say I would like to fix it at 370px.

Comment: @NachoLibre in this case you have to set the width in Popper style BUT you cannot use styles: you have to force width style with in-line style. Something like `<Popper {...props} style={{ width: "370px" }} placement="bottom-start" />`. I don't know why it doesn't work with styles...

Comment: It autoscrolls to top.. any clue?

Answer (score 20):

you can pass this props:

```
componentsProps={{ popper: { style: { width: 'fit-content' } } }}
```

to Autocomplete component

```
<Autocomplete
  ....
  componentsProps={{ popper: { style: { width: 'fit-content' } } }}
/>
```

Comment: The answer duplicates the accepted answer

Comment: @VladiFeldman It's a simpler way than creating a custom popper component...

Comment: This answer is the best one, I don't want to create a custom popper. Just to add a bit of sx

Answer (score 3):

Did you look into 'fullWidth' attribute of autocomplete api?

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Here is an example which I think will fulfill your requirement

https://codesandbox.io/s/full-width-autocomplete-ph30d?file=/demo.js

fullWidth if true, will take the width of its container:

Comment: the 'fullWidth' makes the Autocomplete component take the full width of it's container. I don't want to change the width of the whole component, just the menu itself.

Comment: check the demo link that I attached, you can keep the autocomplete width different than menu width.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I added another sandbox with Select component with the desired behavior.

Comment: This is correct.. this works when @material-ui .. and not for @ mui

Answer (score 0):

###### Custome proper

```
const CustomPopper = (props) => {
return (
  <Popper
    {...props}
    placement="bottom"
    sx={{
      height: "10px",
    }}
    style={{ width: props.anchorEl.clientWidth, height: "5px" }}
  />
);
```

};

###### Autocomplte component

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      freeSolo
      size="small"
      id="tags-outlined"
      options={allTags}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
      // defaultValue={[]}
      filterSelectedOptions
      value={siteTags}
      onChange={(event, newval) => {
        setTags(newval);
      }}
      PopperComponent={CustomPopper}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} placeholder="Enter tags" />
      )}
    />
```

you can use "props.anchorEl.clientWidth"  in custome proper and much more

Answer (score 0):

We can use autocomplete **componentsProps** to change the paper styling in the following way

```
<Autocomplete
        componentsProps={{
            paper: {
                sx: {
                    border: '1px solid lightgray',
                    marginLeft: 10.5,
                    width: 484,
                }
            }
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

`<Autocomplete fullWidth sx={{ width: 600 }} />}`

in MUI v5 you can use the sx prop.

Answer (score -3):

According to material official documentaion you can pass `style` props:

```
<Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      style={{ width: "450px" }}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
```

Here is the demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qon1b

Comment: passing style to the Autocomplete component will change the width of the whole component. what i'm trying to achieve is that the width of the TextField is independent of the width of the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ahh I misinterpret wrong. Cant you directly set style on `TextField` than?

Comment: Again, the problem is not the TextField but the Menu.

Comment: Can you put one example or better image. What you want to do?

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I added another sandbox with Select component with the desired behavior.