# Popper Component Scrolling to top on selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI control - Autocomplete.

In this , I am using multiple selection.

I have below code made in reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579345/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-material-ui-autocomplete-popover)

```
<Autocomplete
   PopperComponent={PopperMy}
   ...  
/>

const PopperMy = function (props) {
   return <Popper {...props} style={{width: "fit-content"}} placement="bottom-start" />;
};
```

Issue I am facing -

When I scroll and select any option from Popper , scroll automatically moves to top.

I tried adding `position:"fixed"` but not preventing getting auto scrolled to top on selection of option.

Comment: Do you want to move/scroll to the last selected item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have wrapped custom popper in useCallback and now it works, so you could try this

Comment: It worked for me, thanks!!! But can you explain why it worked? The bug still doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It happened because custom popper was re-rendered each time on select (and it moved to the top to its default position). When you wrapped it in useCallback and define when exactly it should be re-rendered it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, {memo} from "react";
import {Popper, PopperProps} from "@material-ui/core";

const CustomPopper = (props: PopperProps) => {
return (
  <Popper
    {...props}
    style={{
    minWidth: 203,
    maxWidth: 400,
    }}
    placement="bottom-start"
 />
 );
 };

export default memo(CustomPopper)
```

And then:

```
<Autocomplete
 PopperComponent={PopperMy}
 ...  
/>
```